# GTK+ libGIO symbols for MINGW64

Tags: gtk, symbols, gtk3, mingw-w64

GDB is showing that my GTK+3 application is segfault-ing on libgio for which I seem to have no symbols.

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ff9a5d2dc60 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll
```

How/where can I get a hold of the GTK ecosystem symbols for MINGW64? Or do I have to build MINGW64 for myself?

Here's the complete gdb backtrace. No symbols

```
#0  0x00007ff9a5d2dc60 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll
#1  0x00007ff99d2a01d6 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#2  0x00007ff99d2a07b2 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#3  0x00007ff9fed08304 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#4  0x00007ff9fed21868 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#5  0x00007ff9fed219ea in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#6  0x00007ff99d557134 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#7  0x00007ff99d565232 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#8  0x00007ff9fed080ec in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#9  0x00007ff9fed1adbc in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#10 0x00007ff9fed21895 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#11 0x00007ff9fed219ea in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#12 0x00007ff99d550777 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#13 0x00007ffa1a124c91 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#14 0x00007ffa1a124897 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#15 0x00007ffa1a124a72 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#16 0x00007ffa092607c0 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#17 0x00007ffa09262632 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#18 0x00007ffa09251741 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#19 0x00007ff9a4ea14a6 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#20 0x00007ff9a4f5a9d9 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#21 0x00007ff9a4f54ce9 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#22 0x00007ff9a4ea1ac5 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#23 0x00007ff9a4ea3ed0 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#24 0x00007ffa0925f6df in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#25 0x00007ff9fed080ec in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#26 0x00007ff9fed1b10d in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#27 0x00007ff9fed21895 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#28 0x00007ff9fed219ea in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#29 0x00007ff99d549604 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#30 0x00007ff99d400753 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#31 0x00007ff99d400a2a in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#32 0x00007ff99d272f94 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#33 0x00007ff9fed08304 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#34 0x00007ff9fed20f63 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#35 0x00007ff9fed219ea in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll
#36 0x00007ff99d546893 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#37 0x00007ff99d3e99e9 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#38 0x00007ff99d3eb907 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgtk-3-0.dll
#39 0x00007ff99db8f629 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#40 0x00007ff99dbcb473 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgdk-3-0.dll
#41 0x00007ff9c0cbe89b in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#42 0x00007ff9c0cc19c8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#43 0x00007ff9c0cc1ced in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libglib-2.0-0.dll
#44 0x00007ff9a5d23c23 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll
#45 0x00007ffa1a124c91 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#46 0x00007ffa1a124897 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#47 0x00007ffa1a124a72 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libffi-8.dll
#48 0x00007ffa092607c0 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#49 0x00007ffa09262632 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\gi\_gi.cp310-mingw_x86_64.pyd
#50 0x00007ff9a4ea241b in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#51 0x00007ff9a4f583a3 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#52 0x00007ff9a4f54ce9 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#53 0x00007ff9a4ea1ac5 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#54 0x00007ff9a4f56111 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#55 0x00007ff9a4f54ce9 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#56 0x00007ff9a4e12166 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#57 0x00007ff9a4e27d63 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#58 0x00007ff9a4e27818 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#59 0x00007ff9a4f85cc8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#60 0x00007ff9a4e275a8 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#61 0x00007ff9a4e273d6 in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#62 0x00007ff9a4e304ee in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#63 0x00007ff9a4e2ffea in ?? () from C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libpython3.10.dll
#64 0x00007ff66dc812ef in ?? ()
#65 0x00007ff66dc81406 in ?? ()
#66 0x00007ffa503c7604 in KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk () from C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
#67 0x00007ffa514426a1 in ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#68 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Here are the instructions for building GTK on MINGW from the Gnome [discussion forum](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/no-gtk3-and-gio-symbols-on-mingw64/15058).

Comment: Since this question was asked a newer GDB version was released.
Can you try if you still have this issue with a newer GDB version?

Comment: @BrechtSanders I don't imagine a newer version of GDB will fail to see library symbols. What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to see the library symbols of a library, you need to use the library with the symbols (usually a debug build of the library).

Comment: @BrechtSanders that is the problem. The GTK libraries does not ship with symbols at least not for MINGW, this the need to locally build it with symbols.

Comment: Have you considered building it yourself?

Comment: Yes I have. We seem to be speaking at cross purposes here.  I no longer require help with this issue, and neither do you.